# Call Twoo AsyncTask in the same activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to rescue json data from my server´s url. I don´t know why but sometimes works fine and others the app finish with an error. This is my log cat´s error:

```
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404): Process: my.package.com, PID: 3404
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at my.package.com.ProgramacionActivity$DownloadJSONdos.doInBackground(ProgramacionActivity.java:342)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at my.package.com.ProgramacionActivity$DownloadJSONdos.doInBackground(ProgramacionActivity.java:1)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-30 22:28:00.998: E/AndroidRuntime(3404):     ... 4 more
01-30 22:28:01.188: E/log_tag(3404): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Can somebody tell me why the apps works sometimes and other times works bad? In my activity I have twoo AsyncTask that I call like that:

```
new DownloadJSONdos().execute();
   new DownloadJSON().execute();
```

My activity´s code:

```
public class ProgramacionActivity extends Fragment implements
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    String idioma;
    LinearLayout linear_marcador;

    String results;
    String jsonStr;

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    LazyAdapterHorariosLiga adapter;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    ArrayList<String> elementos_marcador;
    ArrayList<Proximo_Partido> elementos_proximos;

     JSONArray eventos = null;
    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventosList;

    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    static final String TAG_ICONO_LOCAL= "icono_local";
    static final String TAG_EQUIPO_LOCAL= "equipo_local";
    static final String TAG_GOLES_LOCAL= "goles_local";
    static final String TAG_ICONO_VISITANTE= "icono_visitante";
    static final String TAG_EQUIPO_VISITANTE= "equipo_visitante";
    static final String TAG_GOLES_VISITANTE= "goles_visitante";
    static final String TAG_ESTADO= "estado";
    static final String TAG_ESTADIO= "estadio";
    static final String TAG_COMPETICION= "competicion";
    TextView equipo_local, equipo_visitante, goles_local, goles_visitante, estado, estadio, competicion;
    int i;

    TextView competi_portada_uno, competi_portada_dos, competi_portada_tres, fecha1, fecha2, fecha3;
    ImageView icono_local1, icono_local2, icono_local3,icono_visitante1, icono_visitante2, icono_visitante3;


    ImageView icono_local, icono_visitante;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.programacion_main, container, false);

         linear_marcador = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear_marcador);
         animate(linear_marcador).alpha(0).setDuration(0);


         mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
         PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) v.findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);
         pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));

         equipo_local=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eq_local);
         equipo_visitante=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eq_visitante);
         goles_local=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gol_local);
         equipo_visitante=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eq_visitante);
         goles_visitante=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.gol_visitante);
         estado=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estado_parti);
         estadio=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.estadiaco);
         competicion=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.competicionaca);
         icono_local=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_local);
         icono_visitante=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_visitante);


         icono_local1=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_local1);
         icono_visitante1=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_visitante1);
         icono_local2=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_local2);
         icono_visitante2=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_visitante2);
         icono_local3=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_local3);
         icono_visitante3=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icono_visitante3);

         competi_portada_uno=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.competi_portada1);
         competi_portada_dos=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.competi_portada2);
         competi_portada_tres=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.competi_portada3);
         fecha1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fecha1);
         fecha2=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fecha2);
         fecha3=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fecha3);

          Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
          Typeface font_dos = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");

          equipo_local.setTypeface(font_dos);
          equipo_visitante.setTypeface(font_dos);
          estadio.setTypeface(font_dos);
          competicion.setTypeface(font_dos);
          goles_local.setTypeface(font);
          goles_visitante.setTypeface(font);
          competi_portada_uno.setTypeface(font_dos);
          competi_portada_dos.setTypeface(font_dos);
          competi_portada_tres.setTypeface(font_dos);
          fecha1.setTypeface(font_dos);
          fecha2.setTypeface(font_dos);
          fecha3.setTypeface(font_dos);

         new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
                    new java.util.TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             animate(linear_marcador).alpha(1).setDuration(1200);

                        }
                    }, 
                    2500 
            );


         TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
         mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);


           mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            mFlipper = ((ViewFlipper) v.findViewById(R.id.flipper));
            mFlipper.startFlipping();

            Spinner s = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mStrings);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s.setAdapter(adapter);
            s.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


            linear_marcador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent intenttresss = new Intent(getActivity(), Marcador.class);
                     //intenttresss.putExtra("idioma", idioma);
                     startActivity(intenttresss);




                    }
             });

            imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());

            if ((new UtilsDos(getActivity()).isConnected())){
             new DownloadJSONdos().execute();
             new DownloadJSON().execute();

            }

         return v;

        }





    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                     android.R.anim.fade_in));
            mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));

            break;
        case 1:
            mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                     android.R.anim.fade_in));
            mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));

            break;
        case 2:
            mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_in));
            mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));
            break;
        default:
            mFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                     android.R.anim.fade_in));
            mFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                    android.R.anim.fade_out));

            break;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    }

    private String[] mStrings = {
            "Push up", "Push left", "Cross fade", "Hyperspace"};

    private ViewFlipper mFlipper;



 // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Create a progressdialog
                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    // Set progressdialog title
                    //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
                    // Set progressdialog message
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Actualizando...");
                    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    // Show progressdialog
                    mProgressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Create an array
                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    elementos_marcador =new ArrayList<String>();

                    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                            .getJSONfromURL("myurl");

                    try {
                        // Locate the array name in JSON
                        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Retrive JSON Objects


                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("icono_local"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("equipo_local"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("goles_local"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("icono_visitante"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("equipo_visitante"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("goles_visitante"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("estado"));
                            elementos_marcador.add( jsonobject.getString("estadio"));
                            elementos_marcador.add(jsonobject.getString("competicion"));

                            arraylist.add(map);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
                    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml

                     equipo_local.setText(elementos_marcador.get(1));
                     equipo_visitante.setText(elementos_marcador.get(4));
                     goles_local.setText(elementos_marcador.get(2));
                     goles_visitante.setText(elementos_marcador.get(5));
                     estado.setText(elementos_marcador.get(6));
                     estadio.setText(elementos_marcador.get(7));
                     competicion.setText(elementos_marcador.get(8));
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_marcador.get(0), icono_local);
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_marcador.get(3), icono_visitante);
                     mProgressDialog.dismiss();


                }
            }





        // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
            private class DownloadJSONdos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Create a progressdialog
                    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    // Set progressdialog title
                    //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
                    // Set progressdialog message
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Actualizando...");
                    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    // Show progressdialog
                    //mProgressDialog.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Create an array
                    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    elementos_proximos =new ArrayList<Proximo_Partido>();
                    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                    jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                            .getJSONfromURL("myurl");

                    try {
                        // Locate the array name in JSON
                        jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                            Proximo_Partido mi_parti = new Proximo_Partido();
                            jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Retrive JSON Objects

                            mi_parti.setCompeticion( jsonobject.getString("competicion"));
                            mi_parti.setIcono_local( jsonobject.getString("icono_local"));
                            mi_parti.setIcono_visitante( jsonobject.getString("icono_visitante"));
                            mi_parti.setHorario( jsonobject.getString("fecha_hora"));


                            elementos_proximos.add(mi_parti);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {


                     competi_portada_uno.setText(elementos_proximos.get(0).getCompeticion());
                     competi_portada_dos.setText(elementos_proximos.get(1).getCompeticion());
                     competi_portada_tres.setText(elementos_proximos.get(2).getCompeticion());
                     fecha1.setText(elementos_proximos.get(0).getHorario());
                     fecha2.setText(elementos_proximos.get(1).getHorario());
                     fecha3.setText(elementos_proximos.get(2).getHorario());
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(0).getIcono_local(), icono_local1);
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(1).getIcono_local(), icono_local2);
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(2).getIcono_local(), icono_local3);
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(0).getIcono_visitante(), icono_visitante1);
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(1).getIcono_visitante(), icono_visitante2);
                     imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(2).getIcono_visitante(), icono_visitante3);


                     mProgressDialog.dismiss();


                }
            }
```

Comment: This is not the problem of using two `AsyncTask` in one activity. something is getting null. Please post your activity code and point line# 342. Your real problem is this `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of `. Something is wrong with Json.

Comment: But if is wrong with the json why sometimes works fine?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` somewhere. Such an `Exception` can be periodic, which is why it "sometimes works fine". Post your code.

Comment: @Elena we don't know until you don't post your activity code

Comment: I have updated my question with my activity´s code

Comment: I feel sometime (whatever the reason is) json string is corrupt. Log the json string and try to compare them when it's crashing and when its not crashing.

Comment: The json is the same when crashes and when not, is it possible to be for the numbers of request to the server?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 `imageLoader.DisplayImage(elementos_proximos.get(1).getIcono_local(), icono_local2);`

Comment: it's failing at Character 0 - that generally means you didn't get ANY json

Comment: Just so you know-  calling the 2 Tasks like that won't start them both in parallel-  as of 3.0 AsyncTasks run in serial on a shared thread.  To make them run in parallel, you need to use executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Comment: @KirillShalnov: that line can't be, because the code doesn't include the import statements. Also that line is in `doInBackground()` metod.

Comment: The line is  jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results"); but sometimes the error is in the jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results"); of DownloadJSON and others on DownloadJSONdos

Comment: I still think issue is with Json. There is something wrong which could be very small thing to be noticed. I am saying this because your error log says `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of `. I might be wrong but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Can you post json strings when it crashes and when it doesn't?

Comment: But if it would be error of json why sometimes works fine and others no if the json file doesn´t change. And Json Validator says that is valid json

Comment: Data could get messed up in network. It happens. Might not be the issue here but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: This is json example: {"results":[{"id_marcador":"1","icono_local":"url","equipo_local":"Villarreal","goles_local":"2","icono_visitante":"url","equipo_visitante":"Athletic","goles_visitante":"0","estado":"Finalizado","estadio":"El Madrigal","competicion":"Liga, jornada 19"}]}

Comment: This is from first `AsyncTask`. But as per your log your other task is crashing.

Comment: Sometimes crash one others second one.... {"results":[{"id_partido":"1","competicion":"Copa, 1\/4 Ida","icono_local":"url","icono_visitante":"url","fecha_hora":"21\/01 22:00"},{"id_partido":"2","competicion":"Liga, Jornada 20","icono_local":"url","icono_visitante":"url","fecha_hora":"25\/01 17:00"},{"id_partido":"3","competicion":"Copa, 1\/4 Vuelta","icono_local":"url","icono_visitante":"url","fecha_hora":"29\/01 22:00"}]}

Comment: Only logical answer would be `jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("myurl");` is giving null. Is this your method or some library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69932/discussion-between-elena-and-rohit5k2).

Comment: Something is messed up but I can't say what. But Your code is correct. Only suggestion I would give to put a null check on `jsonobject` and you need to verify again the json in both the scenario (when crashing and when doesn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
if(jsonobject == null)
    return null;
```

before

```
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");
```

in `doInBackground()` method of both `AsyncTask`

Then in `postExecute()` method of first `AsyncTask` add this at top

```
if(elementos_marcador == null || elementos_marcador.size() == 0)
    return;
```

in `postExecute()` method of second `AsyncTask` add this at top

```
if(elementos_proximos == null || elementos_proximos.size() == 0)
    return;
```

**NOTE:** This would stop your app from crashing. But still you will have to figure out why json is getting corrupt some times.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be a better approach to implement your AsynTask through a webservices class. See below how I do it on my projects.

**CODE:**

```
public class WebServiceRestTask extends AsyncTask<HttpUriRequest, Void, Object> {
    private static final String TAG = "WebServiceRestTask";
    private AbstractHttpClient mClient;
    private WeakReference<WebServiceRestCallback> mCallback;
    private int ws_task;

    public WebServiceRestTask(int ws_task) {
        this(new DefaultHttpClient(), ws_task);

    }

    public WebServiceRestTask(AbstractHttpClient client, int task_number) {
        mClient = client;
        this.ws_task = task_number;
    }

    public interface WebServiceRestCallback {
        public void onRequestSuccess(String response);

        public void onRequestError(Exception error);
    }

    public void setResponseCallback(WebServiceRestCallback callback) {
        mCallback = new WeakReference<WebServiceRestCallback>(callback);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(HttpUriRequest... params) {
        try {
            HttpUriRequest request = params[0];
            HttpResponse serverResponse = mClient.execute(request);

            BasicResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String response = handler.handleResponse(serverResponse);
            return response + ws_task;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e);
            return e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if (mCallback != null && mCallback.get() != null) {
            if (result instanceof String) {
                mCallback.get().onRequestSuccess((String) result);
            } else if (result instanceof Exception) {
                mCallback.get().onRequestError((Exception) result);
            } else {
                mCallback.get().onRequestError(
                        new IOException("Unknown Error Contacting Host"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the OP's problem here.